# gitlab-ci config, pipeline gets stuck on unit test

Tags: reactjs, gitlab-ci, pipeline

#### Expected

gitlab-ci config runs tests during pipeline and completes

#### Results

tests run forever and pipeline never finishes

---

Project is a ReactJS/Jest frontend app:
https://gitlab.com/futuratum/moon.holdings

Paused Pipeline: https://gitlab.com/futuratum/moon.holdings/pipelines/72013854

```
build site:
  image: node:10
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install --progress=false
    - npm run build
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 week
    paths:
      - dist

unit test:
  image: node:10
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm install --progress=false
    - npm run test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `--watch` flag from your `test` script in `package.json`.
I think you don't need to watch in a CI job.

Comment: Ah! Thanks! Yes that was it :)